# Dropshadow in WPF over other controls

Tags: c#, wpf, dropshadow

I cannot believe i have to ask this, but i tried everything.
How can i achieve the simple effect the toolbar at the top has here?
[image: http://www.filerun.com/images/screenshot.jpg?v=2018_02]
My App has the same structure. I tried with a dockpanel and a gridpanel. I think it has something to do with the border. An actual Border acts as expected, but the shadows behaviour is a complete mystery.

Edit: Of course, after not getting anywhere for hours i figure it out 2 minutes after my post. It has something to do with the background of the elements over which the shadow is supposed to be cast. I worked around it by adding an extra 2-3px row into my grid so the shadow has somewhere to be displayed fully.
Thanks for the designkit, that looks great.

Comment: May I suggest https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Comment: Shared the XAML you're trying please.  There are already drop shadow effects in WPF you can borrow or if you want to dibby up one yourself it isn't that hard to do.

Comment: Do you literally mean the dropshadow underneath the "Your logo here" area. And those context menus are not what you mean? Or what?

Comment: sounds like you found the solution, typically you have make a grid row for just this drop shadow element. I'll give a thumbs up to @Attersson and his suggestion.